# Restoring SQL Data

Tags: mysql

I am in charge of maintaining a webapp that uses a MySQL database to store its info. The other night the IT guy restarted the physical server and then the website did not work because it could not communicate with the actual database. I had to log on to the server and start the two services; MySQL57 and MySQL Router. This made the database accessible. However, the database was missing 70 of the 2020 projects, and the 70 it was missing were the most recently added projects. Luckily it is always backed up every night so I just had to import the backup. Can anyone tell me why when I started those two services that it seemed to start from some old version of the database?

Comment: Without your project's app code that would be tricky. I imagine that stuff isn't being committed often enough?